# Xceed WPF Propertygrid: Validation on Property grid fields

Tags: wpf, validation, propertygrid, xceed

I am using Xceed's `wpf` property grid control to show some of my configuration properties. I am doing via `{ SelectedObject="{Binding Entity.Configuration} }` where `Configuration` object contains list of properties and this object is created at runtime using xml file.

I need to do validation on these properties (e.g. max/min values). However I didn't find any way of doing validation. Can anyone let me know if there is any?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class YourClass : DataErrorInfoImpl
{
    [Range(0, 100 , ErrorMessage = "The number must be from [0,100].")]
    Double SomeNumberToValidate {get;set;}

}

public class DataErrorInfoImpl : IDataErrorInfo
{
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return string.Empty; } }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var pi = GetType().GetProperty(columnName);
            var value = pi.GetValue(this, null);

            var context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = columnName };
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, context, validationResults))
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var vr in validationResults)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(vr.ErrorMessage);
                }
                return sb.ToString().Trim();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Disclosure: I pulled some of this code out of propertytools property grid. It works with both Xceed and PropertyTools library.